# How to ensure thread safety while updating some control from another thread?

Tags: c#

How to ensure thread safety while updating some control from another thread?Can anybody help?

Comment: Duplicate of [ui-thread-safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886/ui-thread-safety) and lots of others

Answer (score 1):

**In WPF** (see comments for details for WinForms): You'll want to invoke the dispatcher to execute your code on the UI thread: [See MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx)

If you don't you'll very quickly run into exceptions as the runtime won't let you update a UI component from a thread that didn't create it.

`BeginInvoke` is preferred over just `Invoke` as the former is asynchronous - you don't need to wait for the UI thread to be woken and the delegate invoked before the calling thread can continue - See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

For example:

```
public delegate void myUIDelegate();

myButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new myUIDelegate(() => {
       // Any code in this anonymous delegate is UI thread safe
       myButton.Enabled = true;
    }));
```

This will work in .Net 3.5 and above, below that you'll have to be more explicit with the anonymous delegate or just define a named method:

```
public delegate void myUIDelegate();

myButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new myUIDelegate(EnableButton));

...

private void EnableButton() {
   myButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: No, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303116/system-windows-threading-dispatcher-and-winforms

Comment: What I meant was: Why a WPF answer?

Comment: Ah :) Mostly because I work in WPF and had assumed the mechanism was common until you asked that question... My mistake. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For winforms

You need to make use of Control.InvokeRequired property

see below artical

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AvoidingInvokeRequired.aspx